# How to include app.js and vendor.js using lazy loading with hash in the names

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, lazy-loading

I have a Laravel 5.8 app with Vue 2 and laravel-mix 4.0. (webpack 4.46.0)
I have lazy loading in my routes file like this:

```
const HomePageView = () => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */"./views/HomePageView.vue");
```

in my webpack.mix.js I have the following configuration to add hashes to the names of the bundles

```
mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .copy('node_modules/lodash/lodash.min.js', 'public/js')
    .extract(['vue', 'jquery'])
    .webpackConfig({
        output: {
            chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash:8].js'
        },
```

Before adding the hashes, i used to load the app.js and vendor.js directly in my .blade.html,

```
...more blade html
<script src="{{asset('js/vendor.js')}}?v={{getAssetsVersion()}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}?v={{getAssetsVersion()}}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

but now that each build could have a different name due to the hashes, I don't know how to do it.

How could I achieve this?

Maybe with a way to ignore the hashes for these two files (app.js and vendor.js) but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the setup I was looking for:

```
...
.webpackConfig({
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            chunkFilename: `[name].chunk.[contenthash:8].js`,
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'public/dist'),
            publicPath: '/dist/'
        },
...
```